# User's email in SharePoint differs from UPS-email

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

We are using SP2013, with User Profile Synchronization.

One of our users has changed email. The new email is set correct in his User Profile, but the old email address is still on his "SharePoint-user" 
( `EnsureUser("dom\user1").Email` )

Is there a job that does this? The User Profile Sync from AD seems to work, it runs `every night at 01:00`.  How do I fix this, preferably  not only this one time?

Comment: Have you checked in User Information list? Is it updated with new email address?

Comment: The only email information I can see here is when I click the link to the users "mypage" (by clicking at the user in the user information list). That email is correct

Comment: Go to Site Settings >> people and group >> Open a group>> In Setting menu, click on List Settings >> Click on list view >> Enable work email >> Save it. Now check user email in User Information list

Comment: There is the old email(!) ...even though I changed the user´s email the new one with powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you can try which will not harm anything.
First try to run this pwoershell:

```
Set-SPUser -identity 'dom\user1' -web http://urlofsite -SyncFromAD
```

Test after this,If still the issue then please run the below command, this will force Sync from UPA to content DBs.

```
Stsadm.exe –o sync –listolddatabases 0
Stsadm.exe –o sync –deleteolddatabases 0
```

Comment: I ran the powerhshell command (Set-SPUser...) and the email changed in the list and it seems to have killed all traces of the old email. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: glad it resolve your issue. i think i will be more happy if you do the upvote as well....btw i am happy :)

Comment: Done!           (15 chars)